# RX vega 10 gpu not showing in cycles render devices

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

I have an amd Rx vega10 gpu but for some reason, blender just isnt showing it in the available gpus. Im pretty sure that my gpu is compatible for it. can anyone please help me out here.

Comment: What Blender version are you using and do you have the latest GPU drivers installed?